# Removing files in a sub directory based on modification date

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ls

Hi so I'm trying to remove old backup files from a sub directory if the number of files exceeds the maximum and I found this command to do that

```
ls -t | sed -e '1,10d' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

And my changes are as follows

```
ls -t subdirectory | sed -e '1,$f' | xargs -d '\n' rm
```

Obviously when I try running the script it gives me an error saying unknown commands: f

My only concern right now is that I'm passing in the max number of files allowed as an argument so I'm storing that in f but now I'm not too sure how to use that variable in the command above instead of having to set condition to a specific number.

Can anyone give me any pointers?  And is there anything else I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of your question says "based on modification date". So why not simply using find with mtime option?

```
find subdirectory -mtime +5d -exec rm -v {} \;
```

Will delete all files older than 5 days.

Comment: or `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -v {} \;`

Comment: What if I wanted to only remove the oldest file when the max number of files are reached when I add one more file in the directory?  Sorry I didn't make the question very clear

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the file list you are passing to `xargs` does **not** contain the needed **path** information to delete the files. When called from the current directory, no path is needed, but if you call it with subdirectory, you need to then rm `subdirectory/file` from the current directory. Try it:

```
ls -t subdirectory  # returns files with no path info
```

What you need to do is change to the subdirectory, call the removal script, then change back. In one line it could be done with:

```
pushd subdirectory &>/dev/null; ls -t | sed -e '1,$f' | xargs -d '\n' rm; popd
```

Other than doing it in a similar manner, you are probably better writing a slightly longer and more flexible script forming the list of files with the `find` command to insure the path information is retained.